# C++ Migration of application written in RHEL4 32bit to RHEL6 64bit

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a series of questions in regards to this and want to keep get things simple, conceptual and something that can be tried out practically.

My C++ application has many libraries some of them are third-party such as boost, antlr, libxml2 etc from 2007. I have 32bit libraries for them compiled with -m32 flag.

**Questions on Approach**
I would ideally want to be able to run the application by copying from 32bit on 64bit RHEL6 os, but I see that it is crashing with segmentation fault. Need separate analysis for this which I haven't completed yet.

Second approach was to compile the application on 64bit using -m32 using all 32 bit libraries and 32 bit compiler g++ 3.4.6. This compiles ok. But I am getting segmentation fault with boost multi-threaded libs. requires some more investigation as to why.

Third approach and will be very difficult one as I need to find the source code for some of the old libraries too will be to recompile on 64 bit as 64 bit application.

Are there any other approaches that I can take and also did I miss something in my approach?

Comment: throw it to garbge... i am joking... Seriously, i hope u get answer

Comment: Sure. That work is non technical and so I don't think you and I are needed for that:)

Comment: easy, run it in 32bit docker container in 64bit host.

Comment: Any link that you can share which has more details on this? And will a copying of binaries and .so work to get it running? Although it may solve the run time of it, it will not solve the maintenance of it for urgent changes. Issue is I will need to decommission 32 bit and RHEL4. After RHEL4 we don't have 32bit on any other Linux platforms.

Comment: to install docker - https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/. if you want to just copy binaries .so, you need exact version of docker image, which will be very hard to find. may be you need to build something like with https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/mkimage-yum.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any other approaches that I can take and also did I miss
>   something in my approach?

You're missing the very obvious one: port and build your application as a native 64 bit application.

You can certainly expect to find issues in the transition to a native 64 bit architecture. But what's important to understand is that these issues will be real bugs in your code, that up until now have been hidden or not detected, on the original 32 bit platform. This will be an excellent opportunity to find them, and fix them.

Been there, done that.

After the migration process is completed you will end up with a native 64 bit application, the best possible situation in terms of having long term support. It just so happens, that in the news this week are announcements from popular Linux distributions [about discontinuing 32 bit support altogether](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3089509/linux/end-of-an-era-linux-distributions-will-soon-stop-supporting-32-bit-pcs.html). 32 bit is on the way out. At some point, you will no longer have an option of running 32 bit applications (since without native 32 bit Linux distributions there will not be any reason to build multilib 64/32 releases). It's better to be prepared, and invest time while there is time to have an orderly migration cycle to 64 bits, then to figure out that the rug has been pulled out from under your feet, your next Linux platform will be 64 bit only, and your mission critical application is not 64 bit ready.

It also will not surprise me to learn that the issues you're having with multilib compatibility libraries are due to the issues and bugs in the multilib builds themselves. The demand for multilib libraries keeps going down; they're in use less and less, as the time goes by; and they keep getting less, and less support; and nobody really wants to waste any more time testing and making sure they still actually work.